# Taking an Input from a file

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader

This is the content of my Input file:

```
0110000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

I want to take this input to an `int[]`, but `BufferReader` gives me a `char[]`. How do I get an `int[]` from it?

This is my code:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("yes.txt")); // will give a char array not int

int[] input;
input[0] = 0;
input[1] = 1;
input[1] = 1;
// and so on
```

Comment: int Array? every digit as a separate integer? What exactly is the output you are looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution:

```
Path filePath = Paths.get("file.txt");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(filePath);
List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();

while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        integers.add(scanner.nextInt());
    } else {
        scanner.next();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {

    int integer = (int) Character.getNumericValue(char_array[i]);
    System.out.println(integer);
}
```

You can use the `Character` class to convert a `char` array to an `int`.